# How view array data from MySQL in CakePHP ctp file?

Tags: mysql, arrays, cakephp, foreach

I want to view MySQL data using array in CakePHP ctp file. What is the error in my code that I can't understand?

```
$this->loadModel('MacHistory');
$data = $this->MacHistory->find('all', array('conditions' => array('package_customer_id' => $pcid)));   

$filteredData = array();
foreach ($data as $single) {
    $mac[] = $single['MacHistory']['mac'];
    $user_id[] = $single['MacHistory']['installed_by'];
    $installation_date[] = $single['MacHistory']['installation_date'];
}

if (!empty($user_id)) {
    $filteredData['mac'] = $mac;
    $filteredData['user_id.'] = $user_id;
    $filteredData['installation_date.'] = $installation_date;    
    $this->request->data['PackageCustomer'] = $filteredData;
}

$this->set(compact('filteredData'));
```

Comment: So what is the exact problem you are facing ? Is that showing some error when you hit url? when you debug($filteredData) in controller does something come there?

Comment: Array
(
    [id] => 11049
    [status] => active
    [date] => 05/04/2017
    [mac] => Array
        (
            [0] => 52634
            [1] => 52457
            [2] => 85693
        )

    [user_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 67
            [1] => 86
            [2] => 98
        )

    [installation_date] => Array
        (
            [0] => 05/04/2017
            [1] => 05/13/2017
            [2] => 05/22/2017
        )

) when I print $filteredData then view this data.

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: Use `toArray()` after the find like this `find('all', array('conditions' => array('package_customer_id' => $pcid)))->toArray()`.  And before `$this->set(compact('filteredData'));` try to debug the `$filteredData` like this `debug($filteredData)`

Comment: There's no context of which file or method this code is inside? Make sure that code is in a controllers action and then you can access the array in the view through the `$filteredData` var. the code you have posted looks fine

Comment: Thanks, view MySQL data using array in CakePHP.